# Vuejs2 - How to compare elements in two array with computed properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, computed-properties

I'm working on a computed function for comparing two arrays... one `keywords` in data and another returned by computed `keywords_list`. When computed compare, he doesn't take in count values getting before by Axios in the first array  ... 
I don't know what to do ...

my code:

```
{
    beforeCreate() {
            this.$axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: '/api/rest/alerts/'
            }).then(response => {
                if ((response.data.keywords.length == 0) && (response.data.countries.length == 0)) {
                    this.alertEmpty = 'Aucune alerte de créée'
                } else {
                    this.alert = response.data
                    this.keywords = response.data.keywords
                    this.countriesKeywords = response.data.countries
                    this.allSectorsSelected = response.data.all_sectors
                }
            })
        },

        data() {
            return {
                categories: "",
                alert: '',
                alertEmpty: '',
                countriesKeywords: [],
                countrySelected: '',
                keywords: [],
                update: false,
                sectorSelected: "",
                alerts: [],
                keywordSelected: "",
                errorKeyword: '',
                successModification: '',
                allSectorsSelected: null,

            };
        },

        computed: {
            keywords_list: function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.sectors.length; i++) {
                    if (this.sectors[i].id == this.sectorSelected) {
                        return this.sectors[i].keywords;
                    }
                }
            },
            allKeywordsInSector: function() {
                if (this.keywords_list.every(item => this.keywords.indexOf(item) >= 0)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },
        }
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: How does your `keywords` variable end up looking after you've fetched data from the api?

Comment: she looking for keywords : [31]

Comment: with 31 objects inside

Comment: but if i add all keywords inside again computed take this in count

Comment: It's possible that your computed property `keywords_list` is `undefined` when the condition `this.sectors[i].id == this.sectorSelected` fails. Where does `this.sectors` come from? I don't see it in your data object or the API call. If `keywords_list` is `undefined` then your computed function for `allKeywordsInSector` may error out

Comment: yes `keywords_list` is undefined when sector is not selected ... sectors comme from props,`props: ["user", "cookie", 'sectors', 'countries'],`

Comment: i dont have any solution ... i dont know what to do ... i cant compare my keywords with allkeywords_list value because all would be true ...

Answer (score 0):

very little information and it is unclear how the api result affects your computed values
The only thing i can say, properties in Vue doesn't reactive. So if `sections` isn't static, computed property `sectorSelected` will change only if `sectorSelected` changes

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: hey thank you for your answer ! yeah i've try lot of thing and litteraly the problem is not come from sector ... i've created a watch on `sector_selected` and console.log appear but the condition dont work and if i delete all old keywords  and add news keywords its ok ... i dont understand why ... it looks like old keywords in array aren't take in count ...